# Android payment API - Chained Payment

Tags: android, paypal, android-pay

With PayPal Adaptive Payments/ Chained Payments one can split a payment between two or more receivers.

I tried to find out if that is supported also by the Android payment API and could not find anything conclusive answer online (which may mean "no, the Android payment API does not support it, they just dont spell it out" or it might mean "I just did not find the info".

1. Anyone knows if the Android payment API supports Chained Payments, similar to PayPal?
2. As I understand, apps which process in-app purchases with processors other than Google's Android payment API will be rejected for the Play Store... Has anyone experience what happens if one submits an app with (e.g.) PayPal payment processing and explains that PayPal is used because the Android payment API does not support what is needed for the app (assuming it's in fact the case, that Android payment API does not support split payments)? Any experience if google under such circumstance accepts the app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its well spelled out: https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html

In-store purchases: Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play **must** use Google Play’s payment system.

In-app purchases: Developers offering products within a game downloaded on Google Play or providing access to game content **must** use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment.

Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play **must** use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment,

**except for the following cases:**

Payment is solely for physical products

Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

Also, the payments accepted via google billing - this **cannot** be linked to your paypal account - the user simply uses this and income should go to the Google IAB account:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410?hl=en

You can use PayPal to buy apps and digital content on Google Play in the following countries: Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Ireland, Italy, Mexico, Netherlands, New Zealand, Portugal, Russia, Singapore, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United States, United Kingdom.

**Google doesn't care what you think you want. You abide by their rules or your app will be removed from the store when they find out.**

Comment: In my case the "in-app purchase" is actually a "hotel reservation." I want to process the payment of the reservation and need chained payment for that, which PayPal provides and as I understand Google does not. Would that, as far as we can (not) know, pass the Play store criteria?

Comment: Actually, that should fall under the except for physical products point. But, you can always send off an email to google - they do reply, though it could take some time. Or check out similar app(s) and see what checkout does. Its best to be safe than sorry since its such an important part and not rely on some random persons interpretation of the rules :-)